# how to convert string field to decimal value in c# crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a string field that contains some percentage(like 5).now i convert that string field to decimal value than calculate total amount.so how can i convert string field to decimal value in crystal report formula field.

Answer (score 1):

Try Decimal.TryParse method.

```
Decimal.TryParse
```

See reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx).